How to index over Datasets in Xarray
I have an array that looks like this:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:              (x: 1536, y: 1440)
Coordinates:
    lon                  (x, y) float64 -8.387 -8.372 -8.358 ... 16.65 16.67
    lat                  (x, y) float64 37.28 37.28 37.28 ... 54.92 54.92 54.92
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y
Data variables:
    SURFTEMPERATURE_V01  (x, y) float64 293.9 293.7 293.7 ... 291.0 290.5 290.2
    SURFTEMPERATURE_V02  (x, y) float64 293.5 293.4 293.3 ... 291.0 290.5 290.2
    SURFTEMPERATURE_V03  (x, y) float64 293.3 293.1 293.1 ... 291.0 290.5 290.2

I want to iterate on the Data variables which I understand to be the Datasets contained in my DataArray.

I found an answer but it is not elegant.
for k in range(3):
    Datavark=list(arr.keys())[k]
    print(my_xarr[Datavark])


The data_vars attribute of a dataset is a dictionary mapping data variable names to data variables.
for var_name, var in dset.data_vars.items():
    print(type(var_name)) # type: str
    print(type(var)) # type:xarray.DataArray

